# Why is my GGplot legend not filling with colour?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using this code:

```
ggplot(all,aes(x=substrate, y=Ca))+
  geom_boxplot(data=weed,aes(colour=species))+
  scale_colour_manual(values="green3",name=NULL,labels="substrate\nmineral content")+
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.22),
              alpha=0.75, size=3.5,
              aes(fill=species,shape=type))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue","purple","darkorange","darkgrey","orange2","grey2","darkgreen","black"))+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(24,21,22))+
  labs(y="Ca mg/kg")
```

to give me this plot:
[image]

but as you can see, the legend is not filling.

when I remove the boxplot, giving me the horizontal green lines and then change the `fill=specie`s, to `colour=species`, and the `scale_fill_manual` to colour it works. So it's something to do with the legend not taking the values from the fill, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having looked at other data the problem is that the default shape for a colour legend of a `geom_point` doesn't have a fill. Change it using `guides` like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

mtcars |> 
  ggplot(aes(cyl, wt, fill = factor(gear), shape = factor(carb))) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.22), size = 4) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(24,21,22,23,24,25)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 24)))
```

[image]