# Ggplot: buggy fill and colour legends for shapes pch=21:25

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, fill

I'm trying to make a scatterplot with dynamic variables for x, y, shape, shape fill, and shape colour (aka border/stroke), when using shape pch 21:25 (those shapes with fills and borders). Colour/fill work independently but reveal two bugs:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$makeModel <- rownames(mtcars)
```

shape - plot & legend as anticipated:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = mpg,
                           y = makeModel,
                           shape = factor(gear))) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21:23))
```

[image: 1]

colour - plot & legend as anticipated:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = mpg,
                           y = makeModel,
                           colour = factor(carb)))
```

[image: 2]

fill - does nothing on standard pch - plot & legend both black:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = mpg,
                           y = makeModel,
                           fill = factor(carb)))
```

[image: 3]

shape & fill - fills correctly on plot but legend colours all black. Bug candidate:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = mpg,
                           y = makeModel,
                           shape = factor(gear),
                           fill = factor(carb))) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21:23))
```

[image: 4]

shape & colour - colours correctly on plot, legend colours are correct but fills not borders. Bug candidate 2:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = mpg,
                           y = makeModel,
                           shape = factor(gear),
                           colour = factor(carb))) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21:23))
```

[image: 5]

shape & colour & fill - colours correctly on plot, legend colours are correct but fills not borders. Fills are correct on plot but legend colours all black. Both bugs together:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = mpg,
                           y = makeModel,
                           shape = factor(gear),
                           fill = factor(cyl),
                           colour = factor(carb))) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21:23))
```

[image: 6]

Similar to as raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75185050/why-is-my-ggplot-legend-not-filling-with-colour), thoguh I feel this is a bug, or at least a feature request, for ggplot.

Comment: Change the point used for the `fill` guide. It defaults to a non-filled version `guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21))) ` For example `ggplot(data = mtcars) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = mpg, y = makeModel, shape = factor(gear), fill = factor(cyl), colour = factor(carb)), size=4, stroke=2) + scale_shape_manual(values = c(21:23)) + guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21))) ` with a bit of exaggeration.

Comment: @MrFlick, please post as an answer? (Is there a dupe or a link to how you know this?)

Comment: @BenBolker The dupe is the already referenced [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75185050/why-is-my-ggplot-legend-not-filling-with-colour).

Comment: I wouldn't call this a bug. This is the default and expected behavior. The guide reflects the scale of an aesthetic. And except for the case where we map the same variable on different aes will the guide not take the scale of other aes into account. Hence for all other aes the key glyph's defaults are used (i.e. shape = 19 but also color = "black" for a point glyph). But I agree that this is special case and somwhat counterintuitive. But I would also guess that there are much more special cases which all would require special treatment. And in the end, that's what `override.aes` is made for.